# Trying to find large prime numbers with Alea GPU

Tags: c#, .net, cuda, gpgpu, aleagpu

An exception occurs when I try to find the 100,000th prime number using Alea GPU. The algorithm works fine if I try to find a smaller prime number e.g. the 10,000th prime number.

I am using Alea v3.0.4, NVIDIA GTX 970, Cuda 9.2 drivers.

I am new to GPU programming. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
long[] primeNumber = new long[1]; // nth prime number to find
int n = 100000; // find the 100,000th prime number
var worker = Gpu.Default; // GTX 970 CUDA v9.2 drivers
long count = 0;

worker.LongFor(count, n, x =>
{                
    long a = 2;
    while (count < n)
    {
        long b = 2;
        long prime = 1;
        while (b * b <= a)
        {
            if (a % b == 0)
            {
                prime = 0;
                break;
            }
            b++;
        }
        if (prime > 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
        a++;
    }

    primeNumber[0] = (a - 1);
}
);
```

Here are the exception details:

> System.Exception occurred   HResult=0x80131500   Message=[CUDAError]
>   CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED   Source=Alea   StackTrace:    at
>   Alea.CUDAInterop.cuSafeCall@2939.Invoke(String message)    at
>   Alea.CUDAInterop.cuSafeCall(cudaError_enum result)    at
>   A.cf5aded17df9f7cc4c132234dda010fa7.Copy@918-22.Invoke(Unit _arg9)
>   at Alea.Memory.Copy(FSharpOption`1 streamOpt, Memory src, IntPtr
>   srcOffset, Memory dst, IntPtr dstOffset, FSharpOption`1 lengthOpt)
>   at
>   Alea.ImplicitMemoryTrackerEntry.cdd2cd00c052408bcdbf03958f14266ca(FSharpFunc`2
>   c600c458623dca7db199a0e417603dff4, Object
>   cd5116337150ebaa6de788dacd82516fa)    at
>   Alea.ImplicitMemoryTrackerEntry.c6a75c171c9cccafb084beba315394985(FSharpFunc`2
>   c600c458623dca7db199a0e417603dff4, Object
>   cd5116337150ebaa6de788dacd82516fa)    at
>   Alea.ImplicitMemoryTracker.HostReadWriteBarrier(Object instance)    at
>   Alea.GlobalImplicitMemoryTracker.HostReadWriteBarrier(Object instance)
>   at A.cf5aded17df9f7cc4c132234dda010fa7.clo@2359-624.Invoke(Object
>   arg00)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Iterate[T](FSharpFunc`2 action,
>   IEnumerable`1 source)    at Alea.Kernel.LaunchRaw(LaunchParam lp,
>   FSharpOption`1 instanceOpt, FSharpList`1 args)    at
>   Alea.Parallel.Device.DeviceFor.For(Gpu gpu, Int64 fromInclusive, Int64
>   toExclusive, Action`1 op)    at Alea.Parallel.GpuExtension.LongFor(Gpu
>   gpu, Int64 fromInclusive, Int64 toExclusive, Action`1 op)    at
>   TestingGPU.Program.Execute(Int32 t) in
>   C:\Users..\source\repos\TestingGPU\TestingGPU\Program.cs:line 148
>   at TestingGPU.Program.Main(String[] args)

**Working Solution:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var devices = Device.Devices;

        foreach (var device in devices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(device.ToString());                                
        }

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to check if it is a prime number:");

            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            long checkIfPrime = Convert.ToInt64(line);

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            bool GPUisPrime = GPUIsItPrime(checkIfPrime+1);
            sw.Stop();

            Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
            sw2.Start();
            bool CPUisPrime = CPUIsItPrime(checkIfPrime+1);
            sw2.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"GPU: is {checkIfPrime} prime? {GPUisPrime} Time Elapsed: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"CPU: is {checkIfPrime} prime? {CPUisPrime} Time Elapsed: {sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString()}");
        }            
    }        

    [GpuManaged]
    private static bool GPUIsItPrime(long n)
    {
        //Sieve of Eratosthenes Algorithm
        bool[] isComposite = new bool[n];
        var worker = Gpu.Default; 
        worker.LongFor(2, n, i =>
        {
            if (!(isComposite[i]))
            {
                for (long j = 2; (j * i) < isComposite.Length; j++)
                {
                    isComposite[j * i] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        return !isComposite[n-1];
    }

    private static bool CPUIsItPrime(long n)
    {
        //Sieve of Eratosthenes Algorithm
        bool[] isComposite = new bool[n];

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (!isComposite[i])
            {
                for (long j = 2; (j * i) < n; j++)
                {
                    isComposite[j * i] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return !isComposite[n-1];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't look right. Given a parallel for-loop method here (LongFor), Alea will spawn "n" threads, with an index "x" used to identify what the thread number is. So, for example a simple example like For(0, n, x => a[x] = x); uses "x" to initialize a[] with { 0, 1, 2, ...., n - 1}. But, your kernel code does not use "x" anywhere in the code. Consequently, you run the same code "n" times with absolutely no difference. Why then run on a GPU? What I think you want is to do is to compute in thread "x" whether "x" is prime. With result in hand, set bool prime[x] = true or false. Then, afterwards, in the kernel after all that, add a sync call, followed with a test using a single thread (e.g., x == 0) to go through prime[] and pick the largest prime from the array. Otherwise, there's a lot of collisions for 'primeNumber[0] = (a - 1);' by n-threads on the GPU. I can't imagine how you would ever get the right result. Finally, you probably want to make sure using some Alea call that prime[] is never copied to/from the GPU. But, I don't know how you do that in Alea. The compiler might be smart enough to know that prime[] is only used in the kernel code.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware that "n" was the number of threads being spawned. That would explain why my screen would black out for a few seconds: too many computations running in parallel. I took your suggestion and used the Sieve of Eratosthenes Algorithm to determine whether x is prime and posted a working solution above. Thanks again!